# Button Failing to Perform Function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, user-interface

I'm trying to make a button, so that when pressed it slides one div away and then another slides back in, however I'm trying to prevent it from refreshing the page but the

```
return false;
```

line seems to break the script. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slide.js"></script>

    </head>

<body>

<button id="button1" onclick="nextSlide('#1', '#2')">Hide it</button>
<p id="1">Hide this text</p>
<p id="2">Show this text</p>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
window.onload=function(){
    $('#2').fadeOut(1);

};

function nextSlide(hideDiv, showDiv) {
        $(hideDiv).hide("slide", 2000, function(){
            $(showDiv).show("slide", 2000);
        });
        return false;
};
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle? their is nothing in the code posted which should trigger a page reload...

Comment: is the js you are showing to us in slide.js? if yes, you should load jquery first. but you should get an error because of this and i don't get why there should be a page reload.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to return anything?  Is there another method dependent on getting "false" back?

Comment: It's a little trick to prevent the page reloading when the button is clicked but in this case it still does. I've also tried to add 'e.preventDefault();' instead but that failed as well.

Comment: This seems to be working in Chrome...I'm still looking into why it's not working in IE.

Comment: I got this working in IE by going to Tools>Internet Options>Advanced>Security and checking "Allow active content to run in files on my computer"

Comment: As far as I can see the code you posted is working fine (with or without the return false)